# Catching error codes of python processes outside of them in linux?

Tags: linux, python, error-logging

I am using a python code, not mine, that runs for days or even weeks. It might have some bugs left, so it might crash once in a while. But I dont want to check it every couple of hours. I know that the python process(es) do return codes !=0 if something happens.

But is it possible to catch that from outside of the processes? If yes, I would like to do that, so I can send an Email to myself if something happens.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to check the return code, using something like:-

```
if PythonScript then
    # Actions on success
    ...
else
    # Actions on failure
    err=$?
    ...
fi
```

Note that the return code `$?` is overwritten by every command that is executed, so if its value is needed for logging or other purposes you need to save it before a subsequent command changes it.

If the `PythonScript` is executable and has the first line `#!/usr/bin/python` (or the path to the python version to be used), then it can be called directly; otherwise, it should be preceded by `python` or the appropriate version.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? If I am running a.py, which takes ages, I run then b.py which is able to check if a.py returns error messages? Because I don't want to mess around in a.py

Comment: Your question and comment are unclear. How do you pass any error to `b.py`? In a run parameter? in an environment variable? in a file? I can't elaborate my answer until you elaborate your question. If you will always run `b.py`, then the `if` in my answer is unnecessary: it could be as simple as `a.py; b.py $?`, where `b.py` is passed the completion code from `a.py` in its first parameter.

Comment: No, thats the point. I start screen, start python a.py, and then let it run its course. Thats all I do. if a.py crashes, it will be seen in the screen, because it will print stuff like returned 1 ... and I would somehow like to catch this...

Comment: I assumed that `a.py` calls `sys.exit()` in order to return the completion status. If it doesn't, you'll have a lot of difficulty in reading strings from a window: although you don't want to modify `a.py`, this is probably the easiest answer.